# Return null or something nullable from lambda in transformation method - Webflux (Intellij warning)

Tags: spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I get the following warning in my code, additionally on dev environment I get surprisingly NPE because I thought that my endpoints return empty Flux and not NULL!

```
public Mono<BackupResponse> getBackupsNumber(
      UUID organizationId) {
    return confServiceApi
        .getObjectsXByGroupId(organizationId) //should not return NULL at all, in the worst case empty Flux, am I right???
        .flatMap(
            objectX ->
                catalogApi.getBackupsNumber(
                    objectX.getAgentId(), objectX.getProtectionId().toString())) // NPE here!!!
        .map(BackupsNumberResponse::getBackups) //here WARNING -> Return null or something nullable from lambda in transformation method
        .reduce(0, Integer::sum)
        .map(Mapper::createBackupResponse);
  }
```

confServiceApi.getObjectsXByGroupId:

```
public Flux<ObjectXResponse> getObjectsXByGroupId(UUID groupId) {
    return objectXByGroupIdRepository
        .findByGroupId(groupId)
        .map(Mapper::toObjectXResponse);
  }
```

And `catalogApi.getBackupsNumber` returns `Mono<BackupNumberResponse>` with the Integer field in response object:

```
public Mono<ResponseEntity<BackupsNumberResponse>> getBackupsNumber(
      UUID agentId, String protectionId) {
    return backupService
        .getBackupsNumber(agentId, protectionId)
        .map(ResponseEntity::ok);
  }
```

And backupService.getBackupsNumber:

```
return backupRepository
        .countByAgentIdAndProtectionId(agentId, protectionId)
        .map(BackupMapper::createObjectResponse);
```

And mapper:

```
 public static BackupsResponse createBackupsNumberResponse(Long numberOfRecoveryPoints) {
    return new BackupsResponse ().backups(numberOfBackups.intValue());
  }
```

Comment: Please show the code of `catalogApi.getBackupsNumber`

Comment: objectX cannot be null as you cannot create a flux/mono with the value null. It would have thrown a nulll pointer in a different part of the code if that was the case. The most likely cause is that protectionId inside of objectX is null. My guess is that the field is null in the database or Mapper::toObjectXResponse is not mapping the result set correctly.

Comment: @AbhinabaChakraborty I added the code of catalogApi.getBackupsNumber

Comment: @MichaelMcFadyen protectionId of ObjectX can't be null because protectionID is one of 2 primary keys in Cassandra..but - YOU'RE RIGHT! In my mapper I didn't set the protectionId field... Thank you!